# how to get single entry from the hashmap even the userdefind object value is same

Tags: java, collections

I have hashmap ,the person having the value integer ,i have put two person objects in the map ,i need to only single entries

```
class Employee{
    private int id;
    public Employee(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.id = i;
    }
}

public class HashMapExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Employee,Integer> map =new HashMap<Employee,Integer>();
        map.put(new Employee(101),10);
        map.put(new Employee(101),20);

        System.out.println(map);
        Employee emp;
        for(Map.Entry<Employee,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+"  "+entry.getValue());
             emp = entry.getKey();
            System.out.println(emp.equals(emp));
            emp.hashCode();

        }
    }

}
```

i need to get single entry from these two entries.

Comment: You can't map the same key to 2 values. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ah, you're trying to understand why it's not being overwritten, is that it?

Comment: You need to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `Employee` to use it as a key.

Comment: @shmosel Excellent work trying to make sense of a very vaguely worded question.

Comment: Please explain **what you are trying to do** and **what exactly the problem you face**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you want, but assuming Shmosel's guess is correct, and you just want to make sure that the second `put` overwrite the first, you can override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of the `Object` class in the `Employee` class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

class Employee{
    private int id;
    public Employee(int i) {
        this.id = i;
    }
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return this.id == ((Employee) o).id;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        Integer idInt = new Integer(id);
        return idInt.hashCode();
    }
}
public class HashMapExample {
    static HashMap<Employee,Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        hm.put(new Employee(100),10);
        hm.put(new Employee(100), 20);
        hm.put(new Employee(200), 50);
        for (Employee e: hm.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Employee " + e.getId() + ", value = " + hm.get(e));
        }



    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Employee 100, value = 20
Employee 200, value = 50
```

Comment: Thanks @David,this is what i,m expecting.

Answer (score -1):

Since the HashMap uses hash table internally, it is not possible, In case you need such a behavior you need to implement hashcode and equals method in the employee class, those methods has to return different values for same object(in your case) objects to achieve what you wanted to.

Comment: I'm curious what you think OP is trying to do.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to understand why the second `put` doesn't overwrite the first, as you surmised.

Comment: can you share some sample code base so that it will helpful for me

Comment: @DavidChoweller No, David what you understand is different from what OP is thinking.